# Commutant of irrep of $S_n$ (over local field)

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, ac.commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic zero and let $(V, \rho)$ be a finite-dimensional representation over $k$ of the symmetric group $S_n$. I would like to understand the commutant $\operatorname{End}_{S_n}(V),$ i.e. the $k$-algebra consisting of those endomorphisms of $V$ which commute with the action of $S_r$ on $V$ through $\rho$.

The only non-trivial result I am aware of is when $V = k^n$ and $\rho$ is the permutation representation. Then $\operatorname{End}_{S_n}(V)$ is the partition algebra $\mathcal P_1(n)$ by a form of Schur-Weyl duality. I'm not sure whether we have to assume that $k$ is algebraically closed here.

What if, for example, $V = V_\lambda$ is a Specht module associated to a partition $\lambda$ of $n$? How can we describe the commutant? By Schur's lemma, it is a finite-dimensional division algebra over $k$ since $V_\lambda$ is irreducible.
I am most interested in the case when $k$ is a local field. In that case, the commutant is a cyclic division algebra over $k$.

In the above case, what is the dimension and what is the Hasse invariant of the commutant? What can we say when $V$ is an arbitrary finite-dimensional representation of $S_n$?

Comment: If the irreducible decomposition consists of distinct representations $\pi_i$ with multiplicity $\mu_i$, the commutant will just be $\prod_i M_{\mu_i}(k)$. (All I'm using here is that all irreps of $S_n$ are $k$-defined.)

Comment: @YCor This makes sense, thank you. However, Wikipedia claims that $\mathcal P_1(n)$ is not semisimple.

Comment: please link to the Wikipedia page in question. Anyway, in char. zero, the centralizer of a finite group is always semisimple.

Comment: @YCor https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_algebra in the section on Schur-Weyl duality.

Comment: For $n\ge 2$ and the representation of $S_n$ on $k^n$ ($k$ field with $n1_K\neq 0$), the centralizer is just $k^2$, acting as matrices that act as scalars on both the line generated by $(1,1,\dots,1)$ and on the hyperplane with equation $\sum_{i=1}^nx_i=0$. This is semisimple.

Comment: Every field is a splitting field for $S_n$. So the commutant of a Specht module over a field $k$ of characteristic zero is just $k$.